# Using string variable to assign phrases to numbers? C++

Tags: c++, string, variables, generator

I'm very new to programming. I'm trying to make some sort of name generator.

What I want to do, is assign a number to a first name, and last name.

Pompt the user to enter a number (lets say 1-13), and that would give them their "first name".

so, something like

```
cout << " Enter a number between 1 and 13; ";
cin >> first_name;
```

And the same code above for the "last name", except they would enter a number that is 14 or higher.

I'm assuming you would be using strings..? I don't know what's best.

So..what would be the best way/where should I look, to go about assigning a lot of names/words to numbers?

Comment: You probably want to use something like a `std::map<int, string>` (or perhaps a `std::vector<string>`).

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on your question.  When you say 'assign names/words to numbers' do you mean you are trying to create an association between them?

i.e. do you mean you're trying to create something where entering a 1 means 'John', 2 means 'Steve', etc

Comment: Yes rdowell, I am trying to create an association where, like you said 1 means John, 2 means Mary, ect. Sorry for being unclear in my question, as I am not quite literate with the terms and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have correctly understood all you need is two arrays with first names and last names. For example

```
const size_t FNAMES_SIZE = 13;
const size_t LNAMES_SIZE = 13;

const char *fname[FNAMES_SIZE] = { "John", "Mathew", "Bob", /*other names */ };
const char *lname[LNAMES_SIZE]  = { "Johnson", "Bush", "Cannedy", /*other names */ };

cout << " Enter a number between 1 and " << FNAMES_SIZE << "; ";
cin >> first_name;

cout << "Your first name is " << fname[first_name - 1] << endl;

cout << " Enter a number between " << FNAMES_SIZE + 1 
     << " and " << FNAMES_SIZE + LNAMES_SIZE << "; ";
cin >> last_name;

cout << "Your last name is " << lname[last_name - FNAMES_SIZE - 1] << endl;
```

Comment: This also helps immensely, thank you very much.  It's too bad I can't check two right answers n

Answer (score 2):

Store the names as an array. Or some kind of dictionary. Here is an example:

```
 int array = {"george", "john", "daniel", "stu"}
```

and you basically have the number associated with it as an index i.e:
`array[0] = "george" , array[1] = "john"` .... etc

Later if you want the user to input names you can use a `vector` instead so you can make the  name list mutable i.e:

```
std::vector<std::string> names;
cin>> name;

names.push_back(name);
```

Comment: Yep thats what we are here for :D

Answer (score 0):

For associating one item with another, a good data structure is a `std::map`.

So, if you want to associate 13 with Oscar, you could use this example:

```
typedef std::map<unsigned int, std::string> Name_Container;
Name_Container first_name_table;
//...
first_name_table[13] = "Oscar";
```

The `std::map` is also known as an *associative array* or *dictionary*.

One issue with the vector is that there could be holes or empty slots depending on the index number entered by the User.

If User enters "3 Fred", the vector[3] == "Fred".  Unless you expanded the vector to contain more than 3 slots, this will be undefined behavior.

If User next enters "5 Oliver", there will be an empty slot between 3 and 5.

With the `std::map`, there are not empty slots.